# Jeep Liberty Brake Light Indicator

Tags: jeep, dashboard, indicators

So this morning my wife took her 08' Jeep Liberty into the dealership to get some electrical problems sorted out.

As part of the inspection they are telling me the brakes (and rotors) need to be completely replaced.

I haven't gotten a chance to look at them but my question in this case is around the brake light on the dash.

When you raise the e-brake the word *brake* shows up in nice red letters on the console.

Problem is that light has been stuck on for the last two years.

The guy at the dealership is now telling me that that light ALSO serves to notify of issues with the brakes/fluid which I am having a hard time believing.  Particularly since it has been on for two years.

Does anyone know if this is true?

Comment: Whoa, you've ignored a brake light for two years? Interesting choice. Brakes are pretty important man. Many times a persistent light is because the fluid is slightly low. Cheap out on coffee or something, but don't cheap out on your wife's brakes. Damn...

Answer (score 2):

It is true.

According to the [Owners' Manual](http://cdn.dealereprocess.com/cdn/servicemanuals/jeep/2008-liberty.pdf), page 202;

> This  light  monitors  various  brake  functions, including brake
>   fluid level and parking brake application.  If the light turns on, it
>   may indicate that the parking brake is applied, that the brake fluid
>   level is low, or that there is a problem with the anti-lock brake
>   system (if equipped).

This is becoming common on many vehicles.